# Bootstrap Vue b-table displaying nested object

Tags: vue.js, nested, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to list the drivers in b-table.

This gives me the correct name of the driver:
`console.log(this.orders[0].order_drivers[0].populated_driver.user.username)`

But when I want to display it on the table, it gives "data.item.order_drivers[0] is not defined" error.

Here's my code:

```
<b-table :items="orders"
             :fields="fields"
             :per-page="perPage"
             :current-page="currentPage"
             :filter="filter"
             :filter-function="filterDate"
             :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
             :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
             sort-icon-left
             small
             >
      <template #cell(status)="data">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.status }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template #cell(order_number)="data">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.order_number}}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template #cell(deliver_date)="data">
        <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.deliver_date }}</span>
      </template>
      <template #cell(pickup_date)="data">
        <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.pickup_date }}</span>
      </template>
      <template #cell(subtotal)="data">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.subtotal }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template #cell(tip)="data">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.tip_from_restaurant }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template #cell(additional_tip)="data">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.extra_tip_from_restaurant }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template #cell(tfr_tip)="data">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.tip_from_tfr }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template #cell(tfr_additional_tip)="data">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.extra_tip_from_tfr }}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
      <template #cell(driver)="data">
        <div class="text-nowrap">
          <span class="align-text-top text-capitalize">{{ data.item.order_drivers[0].populated_driver.user.username}}</span>
        </div>
      </template>
</b-table>
```

And this is what axios returns:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9gNC.png)

UPDATE:

I've added v-if and v-else as suggested and worked for me!

```
<div class="text-nowrap">
<span class="align-text-top text-capitalize" v-if="orders[data.index].order_drivers.length!==0" >{{ data.item.order_drivers[0].populated_driver.user.username}}</span>
          <span  class="align-text-top text-capitalize" v-else>None.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: As per the axios API response. It should work. I am assuming `data.item` referes to the array objects.

Comment: Because data is not there at some point, or it doesn't exist at all for some items. Don't render it if it's not ready to use. That this.orders[0].order_drivers[0] is available means that only this item is available

Comment: @EstusFlask I got your point. Do you have any suggestions for rendering? Because I need to display the drivers (if exist), or display something like 'NOT ASSIGNED'  if there is no drivers assigned yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then use v-if and v-else.